# "fatal: No tags can describe 'e6fbf31baae41b618ff333f3ae55ff032333bd6a" error

Tags: operating-system, embedded, openwrt

I'm building firmware from source code for mediatek LinkIt smart 7688 device from official document "https://docs.labs.mediatek.com/resource/linkit-smart-7688/en/tutorials/firmware-and-bootloader/build-the-firmware-from-source-codes"

in step 5 i.e "./scripts/feeds update" it is throwing error

> "fatal: No tags can describe
>   'e6fbf31baae41b618ff333f3ae55ff032333bd6a'. Try --always, or create
>   some tags".

How to solve this error? Thanks in advance.